# How to save the results from nltk function "most_informative_features" to a txt file in Python

Tags: python, string, nltk, sentiment-analysis

Sorry if this is a noobie question! I am carrying out sentiment analysis on python using nltk. It has a function which returns the most informative features but whenever i try and save the results to a  text file, i get the following error 'TypeError: must be str, not list'. the code i am using is as follows

```
classifier.most_informative_features(100)  

str(information)
saveFile = open('informationFile.txt', 'w')

saveFile.write(information)
saveFile.close()
```

any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Error is clear the type is incompatible, either convert to a concatenated string or pickle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the conversion from list to string to something, or do in place...

```
saveFile.write(''.join(information))
```

Applying `str` to a variable generates a value, but doesn't change the variable (unless you assign it)

```
>>> bar
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> str(bar)
"['a', 'b', 'c']"
>>> bar
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ', '.join(bar)
'a, b, c'
>>> bar
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> bar = ', '.join(bar)
>>> bar
'a, b, c'
```

Comment: Why on earth converting a list to `str` while  you can loop over the items and write them or join the items and write at once?

Comment: information = classifier.most_informative_features(100)  

saveFile = open('informationFile.txt', 'w')

saveFile.write(str(information))
saveFile.close()

Comment: Applying `str()` to a list gives you a string all right, but not the one you should be writing to a file. Do it right with `join` or a loop.